# catalog/products_list not working with different static blocks

Tags: magento-1.9, category, products, static-block

I want to display category wise products on my homepage, for that i am using `catalog/list` via custom static blocks. Below is my code which i am pasting in my static block content.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

The problem is when i am pasting the same code in my another static block to display products from different category it is not working.

Please assist me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Try with cms block

Comment: I have googled it and some guys said there is a problem with name, i need to change the name of `name="home.catalog.product.list"` i did that but still its not working.
It is a CMS block only i am talking about CMS > Static Blocks.?
Or do i need to create from CMS > Pages

Comment: yes cms pages try it

Comment: if you are using the 1.9.2 or apply patches the add your block in permission. `system > permission > block`

Answer (score 2):

From ,Magento Community v1.9.2.x,you need to remove a block of a static block
from white list.

Try to navigate to **`System > Configuration > Permissions > Blocks > Add New Block**

*Block Name: catalog/product_list*

*Is Allowed: Yes*

Make sure to clear cache and it should work.

Comment: Thanx for prompt reply, i have already added that block in permissions that why i am able see it on my homepage at the first place.
My problem is with another category with different category id.
When i display the same block with different category id i doesn't work.

Comment: can you try using this?
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="catalog.product.list.custom.block" alias="products_custom_block" category_id="10" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
change category_id a per your requirement inside a static block. Make sure your static block is called out in that specific page.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't worked!
Is there any other way around.

Comment: I got it resolved :-) actually i am using flexslider along with it, so because i didn't created separate flexslider id for  another category that's why its was not displaying, but actually products were coming :-)

I am posting it as an answer may be someone else come stuck at the same point :-)

Comment: Anyway thanx @Shivani

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for adding it as an answer. Many folks do use FLEXSLIDER including me and this is a learning.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it, actually i am using flexslider along with this block.

Everything was in place i have created the block, got it displayed on custom homepage and then changed the `category id` but because i didn't created another id in flexslider for my another category it was not being displayed on the homepage but actually block was working products were coming from db. Its because of the slider id it was not working.

Hope this helps someone :-)